# "What do you mean (by)" without by?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is it possible to say:

> What do you mean "Internet"?

or

> What do you mean: "Internet"?

instead of

> What do you mean by "Internet"?

Comment: I would prefer a comma in place of the colon.

Answer (score 1):

> What do you **mean by** "internet"?

That means that you want them to explain the term, or to give their personal definition of it in this context - a lot of words have multiple definitions that people use, especially technical or specialist words.

> What do you **mean** "internet"?

That is an expression of shock or incredulity. You are surprised that they said "internet", or can't believe that they said it.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking to someone, it may not matter if you use **by** or not. Any possible misunderstanding will be resolved in conversation.
The **by** probably will not be needed if you are writing to someone you know well.
However, if writing someone you do not often communicate with, the **by** should be used as a courtesy to avoid any misunderstanding.

> What do you mean by "Internet"?

would be best. An extra effort to be clear is never wrong.

Comment: To me, 'What do you mean by X?' is asking the other person to clarify exactly how they define X in this particular context. 'What do you mean, X?' suggests an exclamation - 'Why ever are you mentioning X now?'

Comment: @Kate Bunting  That is about how I see it. I would not use such an exclamation  on someone I did not know.